# Error building QtDeclarative with Qt 4.6.2 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, qt4, building, qt4.6, qtdeclarative

I tried hard to build QtDeclarative with Qt 4.6.2 on Mac OS X (Leopard) and did lots of Googling without finding any cure. Could anyone please help to solve this problem? Thanks. Here goes the error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "QObjectPrivate::isSignalConnected(int) const", referenced from:
      QmlGraphicsKeysAttachedPrivate::isConnected(char const*)in qmlgraphicsitem.o
      QmlGraphicsMouseRegionPrivate::isConnected(char const*)in qmlgraphicsmouseregion.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.obj/QtDeclarative.framework/QtDeclarative] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself:

1. Download the qobject_p.h file from http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/raw/4.6/src/corelib/kernel/qobject_p.h
2. Replace qobject_p.h with the current qobject_p.h file at the location: qt-4.6.0-declarative/include/QtDeclarative/private
3. Just compile as guided